# Why my razor page not show google map?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm beginner in asp.net mvc ,i read down tutorial for write simple map web application:
[this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148949/ASP-NET-MVC-3-the-Razor-View-Engine-and-Google-Map)

So in my view page write this code:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
}

<h2>Hello, Google Maps</h2>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.716948, -74.003563);
        var options = { zoom: 14, center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById
            ("map_canvas"), options);
    }
    $(function () {
        initialize();
    });

</script>
```

but when i run the my project i cant see anything or map,what happen?how can i solve that problem?thanks.

i open firefox browser console and get this message:

```
The connection to ws://localhost:48472/fbc4eb4ba8f245c08d4b7830ea1bab80/browserLinkSignalR/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAVMxSNM8YWkSjTNqVKDW%2FRgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABdm%2BiuJnxhF10BzDr1Z%2B7J6KR%2F%2BuJCWYOVuUONt67r8gAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAACcPWAkFxp3Ue2b%2Fu4pg3M7Y3PvHkDLNZfT2ohQfLpWcDAAAAAeHVeKECzTOS87AKunnn2HMxQVjyac86hh6M%2FTjYF4YXxInAmM5wmBizj7UnQW32JAAAAAPgk7BG3rmPAhFQeTmLPjNLjB2Ow%2FbyNdPE5HyR4%2BRmJG3IdLX2om1zux8pxGME9jhfhw3C3AP0e1r5y1JrLtAw%3D%3D&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A31095%2FGoogleMap%2FGoogleMap&browserName=Firefox&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+WOW64%3B+rv%3A43.0)+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F43.0&tid=6 was interrupted while the page was loading. browserLink:62:20265
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 GoogleMap:33:5
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

Comment: check for error in browser console

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks for pay attention to my problem ,update my question please review

Comment: seems you don't have load jquery

Comment: @scaisEdge i'm beginner,please say me how can i load jquery in razor page?

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi, Just include `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in your view (or layout) before the `@section Scripts {`

Comment: I have posted a suggestion for avoid jquery in your code  ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jquery for run initialize  you simply can add

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

.
this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.716948, -74.003563);
    var options = { zoom: 14, center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById
        ("map_canvas"), options);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

try using

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
}
```

Comment: thanks now get this error in browser console:The connection,no element found abort:1:1
ReferenceError: google is not defined
 GoogleMap:36:5
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: my friend now get this error in browser console:"Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys"

Comment: This is only a warning because you don't have google maps key ..(you can eventually obtain the  key later) but this normally don't stop  t the map  rendering have you other error .?

Comment: No i dont have other error,thanks,please wait to crete google map key,and test,if no have error,vote up your answer,so thanks for pay attention my problem my friend

Comment: The fact the map is not showed is not related to the apikey .. anyway your map div is visible when you show the page or is in a hidden / second tab? or check if you have all the div parent of the map div with height 100% (body and html  tag too)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either Jquery 
or simply call the method at bottom so the whole code should be like

```js
  function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.716948, -74.003563);
        var options = { zoom: 14, center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
    }

    
        initialize();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<h2>Hello</h2>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>
```

initialize();

and it should work.

Comment: thanks,but now get this error:ReferenceError: google is not defined in browser console

Comment: @section Scripts {} remove this section. It seems your google js is not coming to the page.